# Content of one div overlapping on another?

Tags: html, css

Following is the all in one code i.e. html and style. Question is that why the "Box" div is being overlapped on to the "Footer" div. You can copy paste the code and see it yourself in the browser. I have checked the styles and div's starting and ending myself by so far no success. Am i missing something?

```css
.shell { width:950px; margin:0; position:relative; }
#main { background:#f8f8f8 url(images/main.jpg) left top repeat-x; }
#main .box { float:left; width:306px; padding:0 19px 0 0; }
#main .shell { padding:25px 0; }
#footer { background:url(images/footer.jpg) left top repeat-x; color:#b3adad; padding:24px 4px; font-size:10px; }
#footer a { color:#b3adad; text-decoration:none; }
#footer a:hover { text-decoration:underline; }
#footer .footer-navigation { }
#footer .footer-navigation ul { list-style:none; }
#footer .footer-navigation ul li { float:left; padding-right:8px; margin-right:8px; border-right:1px solid #b3adad; height:10px; line-height:10px; }
#footer .footer-navigation ul li.last { padding-right:0; margin-right:0; border-right:0;  }
#footer .footer-navigation ul li a { }
#footer .right { float:right; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif; }
#footer .right a { color:#dad7d7; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:underline; }
#footer .right a:hover { text-decoration:none; }
.box { float:left; width:306px; padding:0 19px 0 0; }
.last-box { padding-right:0; }
.box .entry { height:217px; padding-left:2px; }
.box .big-image { padding:4px 0 10px 0; }
.box .big-image img { border:2px solid #fff; }
.box .buttons .button,
.box .buttons .button span { background:url(images/main-button.jpg) repeat-x; height:29px; line-height:29px; float:right; display:inline; border:1px solid #bfbebe; padding:0 8px; }
.box .buttons .button span { float:left; border:0; background:url(images/main-button-span.jpg) left top no-repeat; padding:0 0 0 7px; }
```

```html
<div id="main">
   <div class="shell">
  <div class="box">
    <h2 style="color:#565656;">Latest News</h2>   
    <div class="entry">
   <div class="news">
     newsstring;
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
  <div class="box">
  </div>
   </div> 
 </div>
 <!-- End of Main -->
 <!-- Footer -->
 <div id="footer">
   <div class="shell">
  <div class="footer-navigation"> 
    <ul> 
   <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li> 
   <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li> 
   <li><a href="Gallery.html">Gallery</a></li> 
   <li><a href="location.html">Location</a></li> 
   <li class="last"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li> 
    </ul> 
  </div> 
  <div class="container">
    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="height:10px; width:1000px">
   <tbody>
     <tr>
    <td style="height:75px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; width:560px">
      <p><a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="Seertech Solutions Pvt. Ltd" src="./css/images/seertechbanner.jpg" style="height:55px; width:660px" /></a></p>
    </td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: It's a mere float clearing issue. You can google "clearfix" and use that to add a clearfix class to your parent container containing the floating elements. Short answer given below.

Answer (score 0):

Just add "display: inline-block" and "width:100%" in your main div and footer.

CSS:

```
#footer, #main {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add class .clr to element has class .shell as below:

**CSS**

```
.clr:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
...
<div class="shell clr">
...
```

Jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/merLdd2y/

Answer (score 0):

```css
.shell { width:950px; margin:0; position:relative; }
#main { background:#f8f8f8 url(images/main.jpg) left top repeat-x; }
#main .box { float:left; width:306px; padding:0 19px 0 0; }
#main .shell { padding:25px 0; }
#footer { background:url(images/footer.jpg) left top repeat-x; color:#b3adad; padding:24px 4px; font-size:10px; }
#footer a { color:#b3adad; text-decoration:none; }
#footer a:hover { text-decoration:underline; }
#footer .footer-navigation { }
#footer .footer-navigation ul { list-style:none; }
#footer .footer-navigation ul li { float:left; padding-right:8px; margin-right:8px; border-right:1px solid #b3adad; height:10px; line-height:10px; }
#footer .footer-navigation ul li.last { padding-right:0; margin-right:0; border-right:0;  }
#footer .footer-navigation ul li a { }
#footer .right { float:right; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif; }
#footer .right a { color:#dad7d7; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:underline; }
#footer .right a:hover { text-decoration:none; }
.box { float:left; width:306px; padding:0 19px 0 0; }
.last-box { padding-right:0; }
.box .entry { height:217px; padding-left:2px; }
.box .big-image { padding:4px 0 10px 0; }
.box .big-image img { border:2px solid #fff; }
.box .buttons .button,
.box .buttons .button span { background:url(images/main-button.jpg) repeat-x; height:29px; line-height:29px; float:right; display:inline; border:1px solid #bfbebe; padding:0 8px; }
.box .buttons .button span { float:left; border:0; background:url(images/main-button-span.jpg) left top no-repeat; padding:0 0 0 7px; }
```

```html
<div id="main" style="display:inline; width:100%">
   <div class="shell">
  <div class="box">
    <h2 style="color:#565656;">Latest News</h2>   
    <div class="entry">
   <div class="news">
     newsstring;
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
  <div class="box">
  </div>
   </div> 
 </div>
 <!-- End of Main -->
 <!-- Footer -->
 <div id="footer">
   <div class="shell">
  <div class="footer-navigation"> 
    <ul> 
   <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li> 
   <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li> 
   <li><a href="Gallery.html">Gallery</a></li> 
   <li><a href="location.html">Location</a></li> 
   <li class="last"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li> 
    </ul> 
  </div> 
  <div class="container">
    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="height:10px; width:1000px">
   <tbody>
     <tr>
    <td style="height:75px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; width:560px">
      <p><a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="Seertech Solutions Pvt. Ltd" src="./css/images/seertechbanner.jpg" style="height:55px; width:660px" /></a></p>
    </td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not properly clearing your floats.

```
#footer {
    background: url(images/footer.jpg) left top repeat-x;
    color: #b3adad;
    padding: 24px 4px;
    font-size: 10px;
    clear: both;
}
```

This will clear the floats of the header.

You can also create the following class and add that to the parent of any container containing floated elements.

```
.clearFix:after {display: table; clear: both; content: "";}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have floated children (.box), your parent block don't know about that until you tell him. Just add to parent block (.shell) style overflow :hidden.

```css
#main .shell { overflow :hidden; }
```

Comment: why? this prevent overlapping the "footer" by .box

Comment: i mean .shell in #main block, not in footer

Comment: This will only make floated element's container to expand to fit its floated children, but won't clear them.

Comment: yes, definitely, i agree. But in description of issue i read only "why the "Box" div is being overlapped on to the "Footer" div. "  It overlapped, because parent don't see floated children in this case. Maybe i'm wrong, but seems, that this is the really issue

Answer (score 0):

An element will float around the next content found in the flow, in this case, footer's text. Check this link for more info about floats: https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

In this case, depending on what you plan for your `.shell` i would add the following style:

```
.shell:after {
  content: ' ';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```css
.shell { width:950px; margin:0; position:relative; }
.shell:after {content: ' '; display: table; clear: both;}
#main { background:#f8f8f8 url(images/main.jpg) left top repeat-x; }
#main .box { float:left; width:306px; padding:0 19px 0 0; }
#main .shell { padding:25px 0; }
#footer { background:url(images/footer.jpg) left top repeat-x; color:#b3adad; padding:24px 4px; font-size:10px; }
#footer a { color:#b3adad; text-decoration:none; }
#footer a:hover { text-decoration:underline; }
#footer .footer-navigation { }
#footer .footer-navigation ul { list-style:none; }
#footer .footer-navigation ul li { float:left; padding-right:8px; margin-right:8px; border-right:1px solid #b3adad; height:10px; line-height:10px; }
#footer .footer-navigation ul li.last { padding-right:0; margin-right:0; border-right:0;  }
#footer .footer-navigation ul li a { }
#footer .right { float:right; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif; }
#footer .right a { color:#dad7d7; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:underline; }
#footer .right a:hover { text-decoration:none; }
.box { float:left; width:306px; padding:0 19px 0 0; }
.last-box { padding-right:0; }
.box .entry { height:217px; padding-left:2px; }
.box .big-image { padding:4px 0 10px 0; }
.box .big-image img { border:2px solid #fff; }
.box .buttons .button,
.box .buttons .button span { background:url(images/main-button.jpg) repeat-x; height:29px; line-height:29px; float:right; display:inline; border:1px solid #bfbebe; padding:0 8px; }
.box .buttons .button span { float:left; border:0; background:url(images/main-button-span.jpg) left top no-repeat; padding:0 0 0 7px; }
```

```html
<div id="main">
   <div class="shell">
  <div class="box">
    <h2 style="color:#565656;">Latest News</h2>   
    <div class="entry">
   <div class="news">
     newsstring;
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
  <div class="box">
  </div>
   </div> 
 </div>
 <!-- End of Main -->
 <!-- Footer -->
 <div id="footer">
   <div class="shell">
  <div class="footer-navigation"> 
    <ul> 
   <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li> 
   <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li> 
   <li><a href="Gallery.html">Gallery</a></li> 
   <li><a href="location.html">Location</a></li> 
   <li class="last"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li> 
    </ul> 
  </div> 
  <div class="container">
    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="height:10px; width:1000px">
   <tbody>
     <tr>
    <td style="height:75px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; width:560px">
      <p><a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="Seertech Solutions Pvt. Ltd" src="./css/images/seertechbanner.jpg" style="height:55px; width:660px" /></a></p>
    </td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Keep in mind that there are more solutions. You could use flex-box approach, you could use display:inline-block approach, you coul even use grid approach. It all depends on what you want to achieve and what browsers you want to support.